# RSA暗号のプログラムを参考にしたのですがコンパイルできません

Tags: c

https://qiita.com/quailDegu/items/668fb0b27e757302a1e7 のコードをコンパイル時に

```
RSA.c:77:7: warning: & has lower precedence than ==; == will be evaluated first
      [-Wparentheses]
                if(e&1==1){
                    ^~~~~
RSA.c:77:7: note: place parentheses around the '==' expression to silence this
      warning
                if(e&1==1){
                    ^
                     (   )
RSA.c:77:7: note: place parentheses around the & expression to evaluate it first
                if(e&1==1){
                    ^
                   (  )
1 warning generated.
```

とでます。

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdbool.h>
#include<time.h>

bool primaryNum(long number){
    int i=0;
    bool flag=true;
    if(number<2){
        return false;
    }
    for(i=2;i<sqrt(number);i++){
        if(number%i==0){
            return false;
        }
    }
    return flag;
}

long gcd(long a,long b){
    if(a<b){
        return false;
    }
    if(b==0){
        return a;
    }else{
        return gcd(b,a%b);
    }
}

long leastCommonMultiple(long a,long b){
    return a*b/gcd(a,b);
}
long euclidEx(long a,long b){
    long x;
    long y;
    long x1 = 1;
    long x2 = 0;
    long x3;
    long y1 = 0;
    long y2 = 1;
    long y3;
    long result1 = b;
    long result2 = a;
    long result3;
    long q;
    while(1){
        if(result2==0){
            printf("%ld\n",result1);
            printf("0乗算によるエラーもう一度実行してください\n");
            exit(1);
        }
        q = result1 / result2;
        x3 = x1 - (q*x2);
        y3 = y1 - (q*y2);
        result3 = result1 - q*result2;
        if(result3==1){
            if(y3<0){
                return y3+b;
            }
            return y3;
        }
        x1 = x2;
        y1 = y2;
        result1 = result2;
        x2 = x3;
        y2 = y3;
        result2 = result3;
    }
    return 0;
}

long modpow(long a,long e,long n){
    long result = 1;
    while(e>0){
        if(e&1==1){
            result = (result*a)%n;
        }
        e>>=1;
        a=(a*a)%n;
    }
    return result;
}

long encryption(long a,long e,long n){
    long code = modpow(a,e,n);
    if(code<0){
        code = (code+n)%n;
    }
    return code;
}

long decryption(long b,long d,long n){
    return modpow(b,d,n);
}

int main(){
    long q,p,n,e,d;
    long demoNum;
    long code,plaintext;
    srand((unsigned) time(NULL));
    scanf("%ld",&demoNum);
    while(1){
        q=rand()%(9999-5+1)+5;
        if(primaryNum(q)){
            break;
        }
    }
    while(1){
        p=rand()%(9999-5+1)+5;
        if(primaryNum(p)&&p!=q){
            break;
        }
    }
    n=q*p;
    printf("n(公開鍵1)->%ld\n",n);
    while(1){
        e=rand()%((n-1)-5+1)+5;
        if(gcd((p-1)*(q-1),e)==1){
            break;
        }
    }
    printf("e(公開鍵2)->%ld\n",e);
    d = euclidEx(e,(p-1)*(q-1));
    printf("d(秘密鍵)->%ld\n",d);
    code = encryption(demoNum,e,n);
    printf("%ldを%ld,%ldで暗号化->%ld\n",demoNum,n,e,code);
    plaintext = decryption(code,d,n);
    printf("%ldを%ld,%ldで復号化->%ld\n",code,n,d,plaintext);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(e&1==1){
```

を

```
if((e&1)==1){
```

してみたらどうですか？

`&` よりも `==` の方が優先度が高いので、`()` を付けないと、`e & (1 == 1)` で評価が行われてしまうよ、という話です。
`1 == 1` なんて、わざわざ評価する必要ありませんから、`(e & 1) == 1` のはずだと思います。

Comment: できました！ありがとうございます